# PSR-4 namespaces (am I doing it correct?)

Tags: php, namespaces, psr-4

I am trying to conform myself to the usage of namespaces within the PSR-4 standard. At this moment I am not totally sure I am using it correct so I am asking some smart guy / girl over here to help me out if it is not :-)!

```
- third_party
-- Webservices\
-- Webservice.php
--- Requests\
--- Login.php
--- Responses\
--- Login.php
```

I am using the following namespacing (Composer):

```
"Webservices\\": "third_party/Webservices"
```

and for example a requests namespace:

```
namespace Webservices\Requests\Login;
```

and for the response namespace:

```
namespace Webservices\Responses\Login;
```

and for the Webservice.php file located in the `Webservices` folder I am using the namespace:

```
namespace Webservices\Webservice;
```

I am not totally sure if  I am using the last one correct, but I can't think of any other way to make it work propperly.

Any help is appriciated or if it is correct that would also be awsome! :-)

Comment: Your namespace root is `Webservices` that's what you defined in composer. `namespace Webservices\Webservice;` is wrong. `Webservices\Webservice` is the fully qualified name of the `Webservice` **class**

Comment: So if I am getting tis correctly if I want to use the namespace `namespace Webservices\Webservice;` I need to change to composer to `"Webservices\\": "third_party"`. But then again I dont think the namespace root is correct or is it then? Cause it is not only for Webservices there are more third_party apps in that folder or do I need to define them all in the composer file?

Comment: Just don't use `Webservices\Webservice` as the namespace. If you do  you'd end up with a class called `Webservices\Webservice\Webservice::class` which looks a bit ridiculous imo. Same goes with the other namespaces too. Namespace is the folder structure and classname is the filename

Comment: So in the `Webservice.php` dont define any namespace? Am I getting that correctly :')?  **edit** U are saying us `class Webservices\Webservice { }`?

Comment: The easiest thing is to just try it and see if you get any autoloading errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your directory structure this is what your files should look like:

**Webservices/Requests/Login.php**

```
namespace Webservices\Requests;

class Login { ... }
```

**Webservices/Responses/Login.php**

```
namespace Webservices\Responses;

class Login { ... }
```

**Webservices\Webservice.php**

```
namespace Webservices;

class Webservice { ... }
```

Comment: And the bombs drop what I am doing wrong here.... I get it know... I was including the classname in my namespaces and then it would get really messy. Thanks for the explanation!